# installation mitmproxy on centos7

Tags: pip, python-imaging-library, centos7, mitmproxy

I have a problem wtih installation of mitmproxy on centos7 x64.
I have installed on my OS:

- Package libxslt-devel-1.1.28-5.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
- Package libxml2-devel-2.9.1-5.el7_1.2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
- Package libxml2-devel-2.9.1-5.el7_1.2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
- Package libxslt-devel-1.1.28-5.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
- [root@localhost ~]# python -V > Python 2.7.3
- Package libffi-devel-3.0.13-11.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
- Package python-urllib3-1.10.2-2.el7_1.noarch already installed and latest version
- Package python-pillow-2.0.0-17.gitd1c6db8.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version

And error is:

```
[root@localhost ~]# pip install mitmproxy 
 Failed building wheel for Pillow
Failed to build Pillow
Installing collected packages: Pillow, construct, html2text, mitmproxy
Running setup.py install for Pillow
Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-JmmUK9/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-sQcNE2-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_py
running egg_info
writing Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

reading manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-JmmUK9/Pillow/setup.py", line 767, in <module>
    zip_safe=not debug_build(),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 563, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 127, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-JmmUK9/Pillow/setup.py", line 515, in build_extensions
    % (f, f))
ValueError: --enable-jpeg requested but jpeg not found, aborting.

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-JmmUK9/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-sQcNE2-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-JmmUK9/Pillow
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the dependencies listed at http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/install.html:

You are at least missing `libjpeg8-dev`.

Comment: for centos7 this package is libjpeg-turbo-devel